# Nx workspace lib structure for Angular/Nest.js app

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

I'm setting up a new Nx workspace for an Angular app with Nest.js backend.
For the frontend, there won't be only a single app but multiple variant with e.g. different styling per customer and slightly different features.

A common approach to structure the `libs` in the workspace is, backend (api) and frontend (client) folders on top-level and features inside, like:

```
└── root
    ├── apps
    │   ├── api (nestjs)
    │   └── client (angular)
    └── libs
        ├── api
        │   ├── core
        │   │   └── src
        │   ├── feature-1
        │   │   └── src
        │   └── feature-2
        │       └── src
        ├── client
        │   ├── shell
        │   │   └── src
        │   ├── feature-1
        │   │   └── src
        │   └── feature-2
        │       └── src
        └── shared
            └── src
```

Basically, we separate backend and frontend code.

Would it also make sense, or are there any good reasons for not grouping backend and frontend per feature? For example:

```
└── root
    ├── apps
    │   ├── api
    │   └── client
    └── libs
        ├── feature-1
        │   ├── api
        │   │   └── core
        │   │       └── src
        │   ├── client
        │   │   └── ui
        │   │       └── src
        │   └── shared
        │       └── util
        │           └── src
        ├── feature-2
        │   ├── api
        │   │   └── core
        │   │       └── src
        │   ├── client
        │   │   └── ui
        │   │       └── src
        │   └── shared
        │       └── util
        │           └── src
        └── shared
            └── src
```

Likely, in the end it doesn't really matter if I keep the libs per feature on backend and frontend consistent but somehow having everything for one feature under one roof feels better for me.

Nevertheless there will also be libs for client or api not being part of any feature, so there's still a `client` and a `api` folder under `libs`.

Thanks for any thoughts on this and hints for best practises.

Comment: [Nx does recommend grouping libraries by scope](https://nx.dev/structure/grouping-libraries)

Comment: You want to start by grouping all of them together. As you work your way through releases and changes, you'll get a better understanding of what needs to be together based on where it is used, what is isolated and what is experimental/WIP.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Grouping by scope (link from @JayMcDoniel) would mean, by `client` and `api`. Anyways, with the move generator it should be easy to align that, as @zeeshan-siddiqui wrote. Starting with group-by-scope and changing on demand once dependencies and releases are more clear.